# More efficient way to check number and add to hex code accordingly

Tags: c, performance

There must be a more efficient way to do this, right?

The only difference in lines is that the hex code goes up by 0x000A0 and what data should equal.

```
void lineprint(const char *string, int data) { 
    // Add 'A0'(0x000A0) to '0xB8000' to get to another line on the screen
    if(data == 0) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 1) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB80A0; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 2) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8140; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 3) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB81E0; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 4) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8280; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 5) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8320; lineprint_print(video,string);}
    if(data == 6) {volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB83C0; lineprint_print(video,string);}
}
```

Comment: Surely you could just calculate the memory location directly? `if (data >= 0 && data <= 6) { volatile char *video = (volatile char*)(0xB8000 + data * 0xa0); lineprint_print(video,string); }`

Comment: If you make `data` unsigned, you can even skip the check for being `>= 0`...

Comment: Efficiency is possibly not the biggest issue with this code.  It needs changing because it is just bad code - inelegant and unmaintainable; I doubt that for a 6 line display performance is much of an issue.  Pick  a solution that is easier to maintain and understand rather than one that is necessarily somehow "optimal" - though it would not be hard to beat this.

Comment: The fact that you might be developing some sort of  operating-system does not make this an operating-system question - redundant tags deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a simple calculation of the address based on `data`:

```
void lineprint(const char *string, int data) { 

    if (data >= 0 && data <= 6) {
        volatile char *video = (volatile char*)(0xB8000 + 0xA0 * data);
        lineprint_print(video,string);
    } else {
        // bad input handling
    }
}
```

Alternatively can be done with array if the addresses are not that nicely spaced:

```
void lineprint(const char *string, int data) { 
    uint32_t addresses[] = {0xB8000, 0xB80A0, /* The rest.... */};

    if (data >= 0 && data <= 6) {
        volatile char *video = (volatile char*)addresses[data];
        lineprint_print(video,string);
    } else {
        // bad input handling
    }
}
```

Note: This array can be made `static` to improve the runtime performance (that is to avoid reinitialization of it every time the function is called) and `const` as it is not expected to be modified.

Comment: I'd make `data` unsigned for not having to explicitly check for `data >= 0`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Sure, but depends where it is coming from initially

Comment: Not really, if original value was < 0, it would be converted to a value far larger than 6 and as we do not use the value any more afterwards, we'd be just fine.

Comment: @Aconcagua You are probably right, can't think of a case it would fail. But will leave it up to the OPs consideration

Comment: @RamdomlyRandom Aconcagua  means to define `void lineprint(const char *string, unsigned int data)`

Comment: @Aconcagua Re: "make data unsigned for not having to explicitly check for data >= 0" --> I'd expect a good compiler to emit same efficient code using your idea or not.  In this case, I'd code for clarity and change the interface based on larger design issues than a potential local optimization.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well, about design: We have positive offsets only and negative ones are (or appear to be at least) meaningless anyway. So from point of design unsigned would be right type even more. Admitted, optimiser might produce the same code, but *relying* on the optimiser is not always best idea...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it could be calculated arithmetically, which might get you code-size efficiency, but for execution time efficiency a look-up table might be preferred - especially if the look-up table is small as in this case:

```
void lineprint( const char* str, unsigned line ) 
{
    volatile char* vaddr[] = { (volatile char*)0xB8000, 
                               (volatile char*)0xB80A0,
                               (volatile char*)0xB8140,
                               (volatile char*)0xB81E0,
                               (volatile char*)0xB8280,
                               (volatile char*)0xB8320,
                               (volatile char*)0xB83C0 } ;

    if( line < sizeof(vaddr) / sizeof(*vaddr) )
    {
        lineprint_print( vaddr[line], str ) ;
    }
}
```

Even without the arithmetic relationship, the original code tests `data` six times when each condition is mutually exclusive - only one can be true.  A look-up table or a `switch` would be more appropriate in any case.

An arithmetic solution might look like:

```
#define MAX_LINE 6
#define LINE_LENGTH 0xA0
#define VBASE ((volatile char*)0xB8000)

void lineprint( const char* str, unsigned line ) 
{
    if( line <= MAX_LINE )
    {
        lineprint_print( VBASE + (line * LINE_LENGTH), 
                         str ) ;
    }
}
```